What is the material derivate of location vector?
What does this equation mean in physics?
$$\frac{Dx}{Dt} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla x$$
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ should be velocity $\mathbf{u}$. Then how to explain the second term?

For more details, have a look at my other answer that deals with the material derivative in a precise and correct way.
In your case, you can view $"x"$ as the function
$$\boldsymbol f:\mathbb R^{1+3}\to\mathbb R^3\\\boldsymbol f(t,\boldsymbol x):(t,\boldsymbol x)\mapsto \boldsymbol x$$
Clearly, $\partial_t \boldsymbol f=0$ and hence
$$\frac{\mathrm D f^i}{\mathrm Dt}=u^j\nabla_jf^i$$
But $\nabla_jf^i=\nabla_jx^i=\delta^i_j$ and thus
$$\frac{\mathrm Df^i}{\mathrm Dt}=u^i \\ \frac{\mathrm D\boldsymbol f}{\mathrm Dt}=\boldsymbol u$$

The reason you are confused and why you (incorrectly) think $u=\partial_t x$ is because the symbols $u$ and $x$ are overloaded, representing both the Eulerian position and velocity vector fields, and as well the Lagrangian position and velocity of a specific particle.
